# How can I run Perl test suite automatically when files change?

Tags: perl, testing

Is there a tool that would watch file changes in a directory tree of a Perl application and re-run the test suite every time I save changes to some module? Something akin to [masak’s tote](http://use.perl.org/~masak/journal/39639).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Test::Continuous](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Continuous/)

Some Test::Continuous links:

- [Video presentation with slides from YAPC::Asia 2008](http://conferences.yapcasia.org/ya2008/talk/999)
- [Run continuous tests on remote host](http://gugod.org/2009/05/testcontinuous-can-now-run-tests-on-the-remote-host.html)
- [Github repo](http://github.com/gugod/test-continuous)

Comment: The video isn't playing for me as of January 2012. May just be my machine or a temporary thing, but if anyone has another link to the presentation, please add it to the comments.

Comment: @Alan W. Smith: It takes a while to start but the video from YAPC::Asia 2008 still works for me.

Answer (score 3):

[`Win32::FileNotify`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::FileNotify) can help with monitoring changes to the file system if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The old school unix solution would be to write up a Makefile and trigger it regularly through a cron job (as frequently as once a minute), and have it mail you the results if something broke.

Alternatively if you use a revision control system such as svn, you could use a commit hook to kick off a build/test cycle when you commit a file.

One other thing you could do is write a wrapper script around your editor (such that when you close or save a file, the build/test cycle is triggered).

Comment: I’d like it to watch the file changes so that I have instant feedback when I break something. Might be a bit extreme, but I’d like to try it.

Answer (score 2):

The basic way to do this is through source control and an continuous integration package, say, like [Smolder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Smolder/). When you check in files, the CI server notices the changes and runs the test suite for you.

Many CI products collect cross-run information for you and can show you trends in your tests, test cover, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ironically I just ported stakeout.rb to PHP this week.
http://joshribakoff.com/?p=106

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any generic filesystem monitoring widget, but here's the Perl specific half.

```
sub run_tests {
    my $prove_out = `prove -lr`;
    my $tests_passed = $? == 0;

    return "" if $tests_passed;
    return $prove_out;
}
```

This uses the `prove` utility that comes with Test::Harness 3.  It exits non-zero on test failure.  Plug that into your filesystem monitoring thing and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed to get `Test::Continuous` installed successfully on Windows, I use the following script, and it works pretty well for me:

```
use File::ChangeNotify;

$| = 1;

my $watcher = File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher(
    directories => [ 't', 'lib' ],
    filter => qr/\.t|\.pl|\.pm/,
);

while (my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events) {
    print `prove -l -r -t --timer`;
}
```