# What is the proper way to test perl modules during development?

Tags: perl, testing, module

I'm working on a personal Perl module to build a basic script framework and to help me learn more about the language. I've created a new module called "AWSTools::Framework" with [ExtUtils::ModuleMaker](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils::ModuleMaker) via the command line tool [`modulemaker`](http://p3rl.org/modulemaker). I'm trying to figure out the appropriate way to test it during development.

The directory structure that was created includes the following:

```
./AWSTOOLS/Framework/lib/AWSTools/Framework.pm
./AWSTOOLS/Framework/t/001_load.t
```

The autogenerated `001_load.t` file looks like this:

```
# -*- perl -*-

# t/001_load.t - check module loading and create testing directory

use Test::More tests => 2;

BEGIN { use_ok( 'AWSTools::Framework' ); }

my $object = AWSTools::Framework->new ();
isa_ok ($object, 'AWSTools::Framework');
```

If I try to run the script directly (either from the command line or inside my TextMate editor), it fails with:

```
Can't locate AWSTools/Framework.pm in @INC....
```

If I try to run [`prove`](http://p3rl.org/prove) in the `./AWSTOOLS/Framework` directory, it fails as well.

The question is: *What is the proper way to run the tests on Perl modules while developing them?*

Comment: If you are planning on uploading this onto [CPAN](http://cpan.org "Comprehensive Perl Archive Network"), I would recommend taking a look at [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org).

Comment: I'm not planning to send this one to CPAN. I'm doing it more to learn about the language while building myself a little helper script that does basics out of the box. That said, I'll still dig into Dist::Zilla under the assumption that at least some of it still applies regardless of the fact that this module is just for me.

Comment: Further research has also turned up "[How can I run Perl test suite automatically when files change?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1775496/102401)" and the reference to [Test::Continuous](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Continuous/lib/Test/Continuous.pm). It runs your tests at each file change. Different from what I originally asked, but I'm finding it very useful when run with `autoprove -l`. (I can't figure out how to get `autoprove -b` to work yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run a single test file, you need to tell `perl` where to find your modules just like you would for any other program. I use the [blib](https://www.metacpan.org/module/blib) to automatically add the right paths:

```
 $ perl Makefile.PL; make; perl -Mblib t/some_test.t
```

You can also use `prove` to do the same thing. I don't use `prove`, but you can read its documentation to figure it out. The `-b` switch should do that, but I've had problems with it not doing the right thing (could just be my own idiocy).

Comment: You should state that you need `-b` or `-l` for [`prove`](http://p3rl.org/prove) to work.

Comment: I'm still new to this. Took me a little while to figure out that before I can run that for the first time I had to run `perl Makefile.PL`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the typical toolchain (ExtUtils::MakeMaker) it will be `perl Makefile.PL` to generate a makefile, then `make test` every time afterward. Those commands should be run from the root directory of the module. See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils::MakeMaker#make_test

Edit: and don't do it all manually, or you will come to hate testing. (Well, more than usual.) You will also want to look at least briefly at Test::Tutorial and https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/testing

You may also want to ask the friendly* people in #perl or related channels on your preferred IRC networks.

*Not actually friendly

Answer (score 1):

I actually think that [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org) is sufficiently flexible enough to allow you to use it for all development. If you aren't uploading to [CPAN](http://cpan.org), just make sure you don't have [`[UploadToCPAN]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aUploadToCPAN) in your `dist.ini`. Also make sure to [`[@Filter]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPluginBundle%3a%3aFilter) it out of any plugin bundles which provide it.

[Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org) may be too much to install for only one quick module that you aren't going to touch very often. If you have more than one dist in development then it is definitely worth a look.

- You can easily interface it with your VCS using plugins. (Including [Git](https://metacpan.org/release/Dist-Zilla-Plugin-Git))
- You can create a plugin to deploy onto your server. Which would allow you to make sure that all your test files pass before allowing you to deploy ([`[TestRelease]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aTestRelease)).
- If you don't like tabs in your source files, you can test for that without writing the test yourself ([`[NoTabsTests]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aNoTabsTests)).

#### Minimal `dist.ini` for non-CPAN dist

```
name    = Your-Library
author  = E. Xavier Ample <example@example.org>
license = Perl_5
copyright_holder = E. Xavier Ample <example@example.org>
copyright_year   = 2012

version = 0.001

[GatherDir]
[PruneCruft]
[PruneFiles]
filename = dist.ini
filename = TODO.txt
match = ^.*[.]te?mp$

[NoTabsTests]
[TestRelease]
[CheckExtraTests]

[ModuleBuild]
[FakeRelease]
```

Test the dist:

```
dzil test
dzil xtest
```

---

If at a later date, you decide to upload it to CPAN:

- Replace [`[FakeRelease]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aFakeRelease) with [`[UploadToCPAN]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aUploadToCPAN).
- Get a PAUSE id, and set [`~/.pause`](https://metacpan.org/module/cpan-upload#CONFIGURATION-FILE).

  ```
  user YOUR-PAUSE-ID
  password YOUR-PAUSE-PASSWORD
  ```
- Run `dzil release`
- **DONE**

Answer (score 0):

In a quick attempt to help you, I would recommend looking at [*Testing Files and Test Modules*](http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/12/08/test_files.html).

Comment: That will definitely help me some of the later testing, but doesn't get me what I'm after to start with for kicking the test scripts off.

Answer (score -2):

Continuing to dig around and experiment, I've found the following two things which work for me:

1. Use `prove -l` in the './AWSTOOLS/Framework' directory. According to the [prove perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html) page, it adds the "lib" directory to the path when Perl runs all the tests in the "t" directory.
2. To run the script individually/directly, I'm adding the following to the start of the script above the `use Test::More` line:

   ```
    use FindBin qw($Bin);
    use lib "$Bin/../lib";
   ```

   This let's me run the script directly via the commad line and in my editor (TextMate). This is based off [this page from the Programming Perl](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch31_13.htm) book.

Using the -l flag for prove seems very much like the correct thing to do.

As for the "use lib" solution, I doubt that's actually a best practice. If it was, I would expect that modulemaker would have created the 001_load.t test file with that to begin with.

Comment: You don't want to test out of the _lib_ directly. That's a bad habit. You also don't want to add code to your test files to look anywhere other than _blib_.

Comment: As I said, don't test using the stuff in _lib_.

Comment: Ah, right, that's what the '-l' does. Still learning about this. Can you help me understand why it's a bad habit to use lib instead of blib? My searches are only pulling in what I think is noise.