# Is there a Perl alternative to the guard gem for ruby?

Tags: ruby, perl, guard

I've been amazed at the power of the [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) ruby gem and was hoping to find something similar to monitor my Perl project for changes and run similar unit tests and livereload out of the box like the ruby gem without having to resort to installing ruby?

Any idea's/recommendations?

Comment: For automatic testing see SO question: [How can I run Perl test suite automatically when files change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775496/how-can-i-run-perl-test-suite-automatically-when-files-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to build on [File::ChangeNotify](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aChangeNotify), which is what the [Catalyst test server](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aScript%3a%3aServer) uses to restart automatically when the code changes.

Unit tests are probably best handled by one of the Test:: modules, such as [Test::Most](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMost).